# How to Do Gesture Recognizers Implementation on Image....?

Tags: android

I want to implement all possible Gesture recognizers on image,like

1. rotate gesture recognizer
2. zoom gesture recognizer
3. swipe gesture recognizer
           and also all possible gesture recognizers.

i don't know about gesture ,so please, if any body knows that then send me idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will help you
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html

and also see this
http://amdroidpinchzoom.blogspot.in/2012/02/this-wll-help-you-to-make-pinch-zoom.html

Answer (score 2):

The foloowing is an open source project on git hub.

[Touch Image View](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

I think it might be what you need...

Comment: As it is an open source project you can edit the code and add the functionality you need. If you can you can combine the 2 answers to this question to provide the functionality you desire.